# Remove iOS App Version from App Store and leave tvOS version

Tags: ios, tvos, apple-tv

Is there a way to remove the iOS version of the app and just leave the tvOS version? We are reusing an app name, but the iOS version which is 3 years old is still there and we can't find a way to remove it. We also don't want to delete the app since we loose the name.

[image: iTunes Connect]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wouldn't delete it anyway. You'd go to Pricing and Availability and "Remove from sale". This is per app though, not per platform. You'll need to contact Apple.

Comment: Yeah called them an explained that I can only remove it completely or just remove it from the app store and leave it. Trying to contact higher in the hierarchy see if they can help. Will keep updated.

Comment: After calling Apple this is a no no you have to delete the app or remove from sale. Ended up using another shorter name for it which marketing wise worked for us. Thanks.